# Hover function with live method in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use hover function with live method but it is not working perfectly, I use mouseenter and mouseout but when I am moving mouse faster then mouseout event not working properly thats why i want use hover with live. here is example [code](http://jsfiddle.net/BCPeZ/)

```
<a href="#" class="add">add Class</a><br>
<br>
<a href="#" id="me">hover me</a>    


$('.add').click(function(){
    $('#me').addClass('abc')
    })
    $('.abc').live('hover',  function () {
    alert(0)
    }, function (){
    alert(1)
    })
```

Comment: fyi: `live` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 1.4.1 and further versions supports `"hover"` for `live()` events, but only with one event handler function:

```
$(".abc").live("hover",
        function()
        {

        }
    );
```

Alternatively, you can provide two functions, one for mouseenter and one for mouseleave:

```
$(".abc").live({
        mouseenter:
           function()
           {
            alert(0);
           },
        mouseleave:
           function()
           {
            alert(1);
           }
       }
    );
```

Comment: Can you add function for hover out in your first example code\

Comment: no its not possible to do hover out i.e. mouseleave if you are using hover.you have to use mouse enter and mouse leave as i did in second example.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery no longer supports `.live()` use `.on()` instead. When you add dynamically elements or add class or id to them and you need fire events on them then delegate that element just as I have.

```
$('.add').click(function(){
$('#me').addClass('abc');
});
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.abc', function () {
    $(this).css({ "color" : "red" });
}).on('mouseleave', '.abc',  function () {
    $(this).css({ "color": "black" });
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veFPS/2/)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar oh i thought you wanna add class to the element itself that's why it is not working as you want. well, edited my answer! you can remove your downvote now :D

Comment: well it is working here! after adding class and once mouseentering, you have to hover away from that anchor element then it will show you 1! this is an alert function. It sometimes lacks to show that is why you can't see one sometimes! This code is perfect you can add other functions to it. I can give you 100% guarantee.

Comment: :I have checked updated one.its not giving desired output in chrome.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22059/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-milind-anantwar)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar i noticed now that you are not the questioner!

Comment: what great? found what were you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method since [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated, and use the delegated syntax

```
$('.add').click(function() {
    $('#me').addClass('abc')
})

$(document).on('mouseenter','.abc', function() {
    console.log('0');
}).on('mouseleave','.abc', function() {
    console.log('1');
})
```

note that using `document` with on is not suggested as it mimics the `.live` functionality. it would be better to use a persistent parent of `.abc` that is closer to it in the DOM ..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/BCPeZ/3/